# Error : expected value of type 'String!' but value is undefined

Tags: javascript, graphql, schema, svelte, sveltekit

I used this code in my stelve kit app.
I want to sent the email to query data from graphql.
I try to use this code but it got error.

```
<script lang="js">
    import { gql, operationStore, query, setClient } from '@urql/svelte';
    import client from '../client';
    setClient(client);

    import { userSession } from '../store.js';

    let user;
    userSession.subscribe((val) => {
        user = val;
    });
    console.log("user = ");
    console.log(user.id);
    console.log(user.email);

    const postsQuery = gql`
        query GetAllPosts($size: Int!, $cursor: String, $email: String!) {
        GetPostByUsersEmail(_size: $size, _cursor: $cursor, email: $email) {
            data {
                email
                username
                posts {
                    data {
                    title
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    `

    const allPosts = operationStore(
        postsQuery,
        { size: 100 },
        { requestPolicy: 'network-only' },
        { email: 'test@email.com' }
    )
    query(allPosts);

    console.log(allPosts)

</script>
```

with schema

```
type User @auth(primary: "email") {
  username: String!
  email: String!
  posts: [Post!] @relation
}

type Post @protected(membership: "User", rule: ["read", "write", "create"]) {
  title: String!
  content: String!
  author: User!
}

type Query {
  listPosts: [Post]
  users(username: String!): [User]
  posts(title: String!): [Post] 
  GetPostByUsersEmail(email: String!): [User]
}
```

I think everthing is good but the data of **allPosts** is not append
and got this error form data of **console.log(allPosts)**

```
GraphQLError: Variable '$email' expected value of type 'String!' but value is undefined.
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong in your code.

Where your error is concerned, your call to `operationStore` is badly formatted. The first argument should be your gql-formatted query (which it is), the second argument expects an object containing *all* your variables, and the third argument expects an options object (`requestPolicy`, etc.). Yet you attempt to pass your variables in *two separate arguments* (2nd and 4th). So your call to `operationStore` should be:

```
const allPosts = operationStore(
    postsQuery,
    { size: 100, email: 'test@email.com' },
    { requestPolicy: 'network-only' },
)
```

This would fix your initial error. However...

In addition, your client-side query does not match your schema definition. The `_size` and `_cursor` variables do not exist in your schema, and you added extraneous `data` keys in your request that do not match your `User` and `Post` schema types. Your query should be:

```
const postsQuery = gql`
    query GetAllPosts($email: String!) {
        GetPostByUsersEmail(email: $email) {
            email
            username
            posts {
                title
            }
        }
    }
`
```

And thus your final, amended `operationStore` call should be:

```
const allPosts = operationStore(
    postsQuery,
    { email: 'test@email.com' },
    { requestPolicy: 'network-only' },
)
```